# Problem with existence of discontinuous additive function.

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

I think I have made a mistake in my justification but I can't see where.

Let's assume that $f$ is a discontinuous additive function. From the basic properties of additive functions we know that $f$ is not continuous everywhere.

Let's take a sequence $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{Q},\;a_n \rightarrow0$. Then 
$$f(a_n) \nrightarrow f(0) \Leftrightarrow a_nf(1) \nrightarrow0 \Rightarrow f(1) \neq 0$$

Now let's take  $(b_n) \in \mathbb{Q},\;b_n \rightarrow1$. Therefore we have $$f(b_n) \nrightarrow f(1) \Leftrightarrow b_nf(1) \nrightarrow f(1) \Rightarrow b_n \nrightarrow1, $$
where we used the fact that $f(1)\neq 0$. Contradiction.

And now I have a problem, because the above justification shows us that a discontinuous additive function doesn't exist. But we know that this cannot be.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: $f$ - function on $\mathbb{R}$? If $a_n\to 0$, then $a_nf(1)\to 0$.

Comment: You consider only $f|_{\Bbb Q}$, where each additive function *is* continuous (equals a multiplication with a constant)

Comment: The characteristic function of the rationals is discontinuous everywhere, yet for rational sequences converging to a rational value $L$ we have $F(a_i)\to 0=F(L)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just from the fact that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ you cannot deduce that, for *every* sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converging to $0$, the sequence $\bigl(f(a_n)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ *does not* converge to $0$. That will have to occur only for some sequences converging to $0$. And it will not occur if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of rational numbers.